# tiny border in librosa.display.specshow

Tags: matplotlib, librosa

I want to draw a spectrogram of a song to be used as feature for image classification with convolutional neural networks. Therefore, the output image must be as clean as possible, without any labels/axes/ticks etc.

From various sources, i have managed to disable the border that matplotlib would draw by default, by setting `box_inches=tight` on the `plt.savefig` method. Nevertheless, a small border remains on any image that I try to draw.

This sample code does not use an actual audio file, but the small border will be visible nonetheless:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np

plt.axis('off')
S = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,2,1], [3,1,3]])
librosa.display.specshow(S)  # i suspect this method to somehow draw the border
plt.margins(0)  # as suggested by Eran W
plt.savefig('test.png', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.close()
```

[image: plot with a small white border that I don't like]

I couldn't find anything in [the official documentations](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html) for the method, nor do I know how to debug this problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margins via `matplotlib` by calling:

```
plt.margins(0)
```

docs: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not remove the thin white border.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found this example code:

```
def melgram_v1(audio_file_path, to_file):
   sig, fs = librosa.load(audio_file_path)

   plt.axis('off')  # no axis
   plt.axes([0., 0., 1., 1.], frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])  # Remove the white edge
   S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=sig, sr=fs)
   librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max))
   plt.savefig(to_file, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0)
   plt.close()
```